# What does Hinduism say about female masturbation?

Tags: women, sex, feminism

Women in past were generally thought of as inferior to men, and thus there were a lot of things that women were restricted from practicing (and often punished if found guilty for practicing the same) while men weren't, for example polygamy, so I was wondering what really does Hinduism say about ***"Female Masturbation"*** is self-love considered a sin (especially for women)?

Comment: it is prohibited for men too.